# a4j:commandbutton actionlistener is not getting called

Tags: richfaces, jsf-2.2

I am using richfaces 4.5.2 with jsf 2.2.6. In my child window I have a a4j:commandbutton. actionlistener of that commandbutton is not getting called. here is the code below. Can anyone tell why the actionlistener is not getting called.

```
<a4j:commandButton id="partsChoiceAddBtn"
                    value="Add Selection"
                    onclick="showProcessingDialog();dialog_close('lT:choicesForm:choices_dialog');"
                    actionListener="#{lineItemController.savePartsChoice}"
                    oncomplete="dialog_close('processingDialog');"
                    render="lT:item_entry_form,lT:F, hF:isfHeader_filing_status_box">
                    <f:param name="conversationId" value="#{conversation.id}" />
                </a4j:commandButton>
```

Comment: Check if there is not error in javascript called in `onclick` or temporary remove `onclick` attribute and see if action listener is called.

Comment: There is no error in javascript called in onclick and i tried removing onclick attribute, action listener is not called.